# How can provide JsonFormats for case class that references itself?

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

How can provide JsonFormats for case class that references itself ?

I'm following **[this](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes)** guideline and wrote following code

```
case class Item(name: String, desc: Option[String], prices: Array[String], subitems: Option[List[Item]])

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._ // !!! IMPORTANT, else `convertTo` and `toJson` won't work

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val menuItemFormat = jsonFormat(Item, "name", "desc", "prices", "subitems")
}

import MyJsonProtocol._
```

and I get following error message meaning of which I unfortunately don't understand.

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Hi.MyJsonProtocol.JF[Option[List[mypkg.Item]]]
    implicit val menuItemFormat = jsonFormat(Item, "name", "desc", "prices", "subitems")
                             ^
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the recursive implicit to find itself, you need to give it an explicit type definition.  Change your implicit to:

```
implicit val menuItemFormat: RootJsonFormat[Item] = jsonFormat(Item.apply, "name", "desc", "prices", "subitems")
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at this related question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451042/npe-in-spray-json-because-of-confusing-implicits-context-bound-issue

Comment: For completion sake https://github.com/spray/spray-json#jsonformats-for-recursive-types