# NPE in spray-json because of recursive implicits (context bound issue?)

Tags: scala, implicit, context-bound, spray-json

Perhaps I discovered a [bug](http://goo.gl/C79j8) in spray-json. I get Null Pointer Exception when I'm trying to get json of an object that has field of type of itself. Example is:

```
case class TestItem(subitems: Option[List[TestItem]])

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val testItemFormat: RootJsonFormat[TestItem] = jsonFormat(TestItem, "subitems")
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

object TestNPE {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val subitems = List(TestItem(None))
    val item: TestItem = TestItem(Option(subitems))
    val jsonAst = item.toJson
    val json = jsonAst.prettyPrint
    println(json)
  }
}
```

And call-stack is this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at spray.json.PimpedAny.toJson(package.scala:40)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CollectionFormats.scala:26)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1$$anonfun$write$1.apply(CollectionFormats.scala:26)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:26)
    at spray.json.CollectionFormats$$anon$1.write(CollectionFormats.scala:25)
    at spray.json.PimpedAny.toJson(package.scala:40)
    at spray.json.StandardFormats$OptionFormat.write(StandardFormats.scala:34)
    at spray.json.StandardFormats$OptionFormat.write(StandardFormats.scala:32)
    at spray.json.ProductFormats$class.productElement2Field(ProductFormats.scala:473)
    at spray.json.MyJsonProtocol$.productElement2Field(TestNPE.scala:5)
    at spray.json.ProductFormats$$anon$1.write(ProductFormats.scala:32)
    at spray.json.ProductFormats$$anon$1.write(ProductFormats.scala:30)
    at spray.json.PimpedAny.toJson(package.scala:40)
    at spray.json.TestNPE$.main(TestNPE.scala:18)
    at spray.json.TestNPE.main(TestNPE.scala)
```

Sooo I tried to fix it myself but my knowledge of Scala is not strong enough yet. NPE happens [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/master/src/main/scala/spray/json/package.scala#L39) when it's attempting to convert inner `TestItem`. Function parameter `write` at that moment is `null`.

Could you please explain to me why it doesn't use my implicit instead ? I see in the debugger that instead of using my implicit `write` contains value of some magic field `evidence$x$y` which changes as it [goes deeper in calling chain](http://snag.gy/xOSSs.jpg). I don't know what it is. I feel like it's something related to context bound but reading [relevant chapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644) didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I should have been more attentive. I had to use `lazyFormat` wrapper.